# A.Speak("Hello {0}, How are you today", name);

Tags: c#

I need help for this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer A = new SpeechSynthesizer();

            A.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Neutral);
            A.Speak("Hello, my name is Ezou. What's yours?");
            Console.Write(">>>>>>");
          var name = Console.ReadLine();
            A.Speak("Hello " + name );
            A.Speak("How are you today?");
            A.Speak("Hello {0}, How are you today", name);

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is here :

A.Speak("Hello {0}, How are you today", name);

There is error on the Speak part

Comment: And the error is.... ?

Comment: Read the documentation for the overload of Speak https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speak(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could probably come up with a more descriptive title for your question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any [overload of the `Speak()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx) which accepts two strings.  So you can't pass it two strings.  It looks like you want to use `string.Format()` to create a single string, so do exactly that:

```
A.Speak(string.Format("Hello {0}, How are you today", name));
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you've got two options.

As David suggested in his answer, you could use:

```
A.Speak(string.Format("Hello {0}, how are you today?", name));
```

and another thing you could do is as follows:

```
A.Speak($"Hello {name}, how are you today?");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no overloaded [`Speak()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speak(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `SpeechSynthesizer` class that accepts two parameters of type string, probably you can try like this:

```
A.Speak(String.Format("Hello {0}, How are you today", name));
```

Here the `String.Format` will give you the formatted string as input to the `Speak()`